# How can I display the p-value in a correlation Plot in the right size?

Tags: r, plot, correlation, p-value, r-corrplot

I have plotted a correlation matrix resulting from the function "rcorr" with "corrplot". Everything comes out fine so far, except one thing. I would like to display the p-value for either all, or for at least the cells, where the p-value is higher than the previously defined significance level of 0.005. The "insig" function does display the the p-values for the cells with p<sig, but I can't change the size of the plotted numbers. I tried to use any of the given arguments of the "corrplot" function, but it has no effect of the size of the p-value text. Does anyone know how I could change the size and how I can control the position of the p-values in each cell?

Here is the code I am using:

```
my_data <- FS[,2:27]

# Mark the insignificant coefficients according to the specified p-value significance level
library(corrplot)
library(Hmisc)
FScor <- rcorr(as.matrix(my_data[,1:25],method = c("spearman")))
M_Konz <- FScor$r
p_matK <- FScor$P
CorrKonz <- corrplot(M_Konz, type = "upper", order = "hclust", insig = "p-value",
                     p.mat = p_matK, sig.level = 0.005,
                     tl.cex = 0.7,tl.col = "black",
                     title = "")
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `corrplot` does not give you direct control over the size of the p-values, but you can get it by setting the graphics parameter directly. You did not provide reproducible data so I'll use an example from the `corrplot` vignette. Your code has a problem with the `rcorr` line since `method=` is not an argument of `as.matrix` or `rcorr`.

```
M <- rcorr(as.matrix(mtcars), type="spearman")
Mr <- M$r
Mp <- M$P
oldp <- par(cex=.75)
Mcorr <- corrplot(Mr, type = "upper", order = "hclust", insig = "p-value",
              p.mat = Mp, sig.level = 0.005, tl.cex = 1.25, tl.col = "black",
              cl.cex=1.25, title = "")
par(oldp)
```

The `mtcars` data frame is included with R. We set the graphical parameter `cex` to .75 (default is 1) and then increase the size of the variable labels with `tl.cex` and the legend labels with `cl.cex`. After drawing the plot we reset the default graphics parameters.

[image: Corrplot]